# How do I ask for a PyQt5 example in documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

I saw an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pyqt/1715/introduction-to-pyqt/8618/a-basic-application) in PyQt4. How can I ask for the same in PyQt5?

Comment: Flag the topic, ask for the example.